# "Error Loading Operating system" when booting from usb to install 12.10 64bit

Tags: 12.10, usb, ssd

I have just built a new computer I've never installed Linux on a computer before.

booting from my usb come up with "error loading operating system". I am trying to install it on my new 64gb SSD, it has nothing on it. looked through some of the previous forums but most of theirs have been because they have already got windows already installed on it.

Could someone please help?

Comment: What tool did you use to make the USB key, that didn't warn you about the NTFS filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make you USB bootable with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and then in your BIOS set boot priority to boot first from your USB. Then it should work fine. After you install Ubuntu, remove your USB and pc should boot into the Ubuntu installed on your drive.

Comment: [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) can also be used to make bootable ubuntu usb, which is a tool prescribed in Ubuntu website.

Comment: It is still coming up with "Error loading operating system" any other suggestions?

Comment: did you set up bios correctly?

Comment: It boots up this time, but when I try and install it it just keeps restarting same when I try and run it from it

Comment: does it restarts right as you choose to install or boot without doing anything?

Comment: yeah it restarts after I have chosen each option and then goes back to the beginning screen

Comment: is it a new computer?

Comment: yes, built just today

Comment: I know its the flash stick/ubuntu file since I just tried it on my laptop that works, and it behaved in the same manner

Comment: try to format usb and make new one with unetbootin. sometimes it just make some errors.

Comment: My housemate suggested I try it in FAT32 format instead of NTFS and it worked right away

Comment: of course. i forget to tell you this. usb will not boot from ntfs, only from fat32.

Comment: @user127259 please post your solution as an answer and mark it as the solution / best answer :)